# How to delete item under View_Type header in RecyclerView when using SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of videos which is shown under header like Today,Yesterday etc. If user selects any one video it should delete that. Currently I am able to achieve deleting functionality, but the problem is that the item which is getting deleted is not the correct one. When I try to get the position of item using holder.getAdapterPosition then it's giving me position including the header which I don't want.

Below is the call which I am making in onBindViewHolder:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(video_files.get(position).getPath()));
        Glide.with(mContext).load(uri)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.video_placeholder).error(R.drawable.video_placeholder))
                .into(holder.iv_videoPreview);
        if(isLongPressClicked){
            holder.iv_delete_overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            holder.iv_delete_overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.iv_play.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                boolean isLongPressed;
                if(isLongPressClicked){
                    isLongPressed =false;
                }else{
                    isLongPressed =true;
                }

                iGalleryVideoClickListener.onVideoLongClick(v, holder.getAdapterPosition(), isLongPressed);
                return true;
            }
        });

        holder.iv_delete_overlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iGalleryVideoClickListener.onOverlayClick(v, holder.getAdapterPosition(),sections);
            }
        });
    }
```

Code to set header with the list:

```
//This is the code to provide a sectioned grid
        List<SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter.Section> sections = new ArrayList<SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter.Section>();

        for (int i = 0; i < headerPos.size(); i++) {
            sections.add(new SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(headerPos.get(i), headerText.get(i)));
        }

        //Add your adapter to the sectionAdapter
        SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[] dummy = new SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[sections.size()];
        SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter mSectionedAdapter = new SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.gallery_header, R.id.section_text, mRecyclerView, mAdapter);
        mSectionedAdapter.setSections(sections.toArray(dummy));
        //Apply this adapter to the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mSectionedAdapter);
```

Below is my method to delete file:

```
  public void deleteSingleVideo(View v, int pos, List<SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter.Section> sections){

            Uri mediaStoreUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(video_files.get(pos).getPath()));
            File fdelete = new File(mediaStoreUri.getPath());
            fdelete.delete();
            ((ReviewFragment)fragment).refreshScreenAfterDeletion();
    }
```

Everything works fine is just the position I am not getting correctly. How to get the position of only video file excluding header position.

Comment: How are you showing header_view? Is `onBindViewHolder` not called for header_view?

Comment: @user10284284 I have created another adapter for header and that adapter I am setting with the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem like you are using [SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/e81e126227f8a4bb339c).

You will need to use `mSectionedAdapter.sectionedPositionToPosition(int position)` to get the actual position of item.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really save my day.